# Instanced drawing with OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl, glsles

**In short:**

Can anyone confirm whether it is possible to use the built-in variable `gl_InstanceID` (or `gl_InstanceIDEXT`) in a vertex shader using OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS with `GL_EXT_draw_instanced` enabled?

---

**Longer:**

I want to draw multiple instances of an object using [glDrawArraysInstanced](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glDrawArraysInstanced.xhtml) and [gl_InstanceID](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/gl_InstanceID.xhtml), and I want my application to run on multiple platforms, including iOS.

The specification clearly says that these features require ES 3.0. According to the [iOS Device Compatibility Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH106-SW1) ES 3.0 is only available on a few devices (those based on the A7 GPU; so iPhone 5s, but not on iPhone 5 or earlier).

So my first assumption was that I needed to avoid using instanced drawing on older iOS devices.

However, [further down](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH106-SW7) in the compatibility reference document it says that the [EXT_draw_instanced](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/draw_instanced.txt) extension is supported for all SGX Series 5 processors (that includes iPhone 5 and 4s).

This makes me think that I could indeed use instanced drawing on older iOS devices too, by looking up and using the appropriate extension function (EXT or ARB) for [glDrawArraysInstanced](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glDrawArraysInstanced.xhtml).

I'm currently just running some test code using [SDL](http://libsdl.org/) and [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) on Windows so I haven't tested anything on iOS yet.

However, in my current setup I'm having trouble using the [gl_InstanceID](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/gl_InstanceID.xhtml) built-in variable in a vertex shader. I'm getting the following error message:

> 'gl_InstanceID' : variable is not available in current GLSL version

Enabling the "draw_instanced" extension in GLSL has no effect:

```
#extension GL_ARB_draw_instanced : enable
#extension GL_EXT_draw_instanced : enable
```

The error goes away when I specifically declare that I need ES 3.0 (GLSL 300 ES):

```
#version 300 es
```

Although that seem to work fine on my Windows desktop machine in an ES 2.0 context I doubt that this would work on an iPhone 5.

So, shall I abandon the idea of being able to use instanced drawing on older iOS devices?

Comment: According to the documentation for the extension, it makes the variable `gl_InstanceIDEXT` available in the vertex shader. If Apple say they support that extension, then it should work.

Comment: Okay. But I'm confused. My Windows machine says that it supports `ARB_draw_instanced` but neither `gl_InstanceID` or `gl_InstanceIDARB` is available in GLSL when I target ES 2.0. Should I not be concerned about that, or might it be an indication that the same problem applies to `EXT_draw_instanced` on iOS?

Comment: Is `gl_InstanceIDEXT` available if you enable `GL_EXT_draw_instanced` in the shader? Either way, I don't think you can infer very much about the iOS implementation from the behaviour on your Windows machine.

Comment: @GuyRT: No it is not available even if I enable the extension. So are you saying that I should think of this as an abnormality on my Windows machine and assume that it just will work on iOS with the extension enabled?

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as "assume that it just will work". Just don't think it won't work because it doesn't on your PC

Comment: Apple supports instanced draws in OpenGL ES 2.0

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3ddrawing/conceptual/opengles_programmingguide/Performance/Performance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH105-SW20

"Instanced drawing is available in the core OpenGL ES 3.0 API and in OpenGL ES 2.0 through the EXT_draw_instanced and EXT_instanced_arrays extensions."

It's available on all of their GPUs according to this..
 https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html

Comment: Thanks Shammi! That's exactly the confirmation I was looking for. Can't believe I missed that sentence. Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: Does your Windows ES 2.0 driver export that extension as supported under an ES 2.0 context? If it does it may be a driver bug stopping you from using it. ES 2.0 is not what I'd consider a primary API for desktop devices, so the GPU vendor may be unaware of this if it is a bug.

Comment: @MårtenWikström  Is instancing  working in openGLES2.0 ? I'm was not able to use gl_InstanceID in my shader.

Comment: I found a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28041936/use-of-undeclared-identifier-gl-instanceid/28043341#28043341. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Performance/Performance.html):

> Instanced drawing is available in the core OpenGL ES 3.0 API and in
>   OpenGL ES 2.0 through the EXT_draw_instanced and EXT_instanced_arrays
>   extensions.

[You can see](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html) that it's available on all of their GPUs, PowerVR SGX, Apple A7, A8.

(Looks like @Shammi's not coming back... if they do, you can change the accepted answer :)

Comment: PowerVR SGX 535 and later.  So iPhone 3GS & newer (every iDevice except the original iPhone, iPhone 3G, iPod Touch 1st gen or 2nd gen).