# Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_InstanceID'

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

Hi everyone, i have been trying Instanced drawing in OpenGLES2.0, in IOS platform. My rendering code

```
 glEnableVertexAttribArray(...);
 glVertexAttribPointer(...)
 glDrawElementsInstancedEXT(GL_TRIANGLES,IndicesCount, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0, 5);
```

And my Vertex Shader

```
attribute vec4 VertPosition;
uniform mat4 mvpMatrix[600];

void main()
{
    gl_Position = (mvpMatrix[gl_InstanceID]) * VertPosition;
}
```

I'm getting ERROR: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_InstanceID'

my glsl version is 1.0, if version is the issue then how can i upgrade ? Any other way to use "gl_InstanceID" in GLSL ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gl_InstanceID is only available starting from GLSL ES 3.0 as stated [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.khronos.org%2Fopengles%2Fsdk%2Fdocs%2Fman3%2Fhtml%2Fgl_InstanceID.xhtml&ei=RjC-VPWbK8vWPcSSgLAK&usg=AFQjCNHixeMOCZ3tQZOLqwyuH1rP8QuihQ&sig2=u0UtMmSKzFibRykQ2aBkwg).

So this is, as you already suspected, a version issue. As far as I know, the only available GLSL ES version in OpenGL ES 2.0 is GLSL ES 1.0, and if you want to use a higher GLSL ES version you have to upgrade to OpenGL ES 3.0. (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872105/what-versions-of-glsl-can-i-use-in-opengl-es-2-0))

Edit: I was thinking about what you want to achieve with the usage of gl_InstanceID. This variable does only make sense when using one of the instanced draw commands (glDrawArraysInstanced etc.), which are also not available in ES 2.0.

Apparently, there is a possibility to use instanced rendering in OpenGL ES 2.0 by using the [GL_EXT_draw_instanced](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/draw_instanced.txt) extension. This extension provides one with two additional draw commands for instanced drawing (glDrawElementsInstancedEXT and glDrawArraysInstancedEXT). When using the extension, one has to enable it in the shader

```
#extension GL_EXT_draw_instanced : enable
```

and use gl_InstanceIDEXT instead of gl_InstanceID.

Comment: but here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387959/instanced-drawing-with-opengl-es-2-0-on-ios  they discussed about the possibility of instancing in opengles2.0.

Comment: Yes it is possible when using extensions. But then you have to enable them in your shader as shown in the link and use gl_InstanceIDEXT.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. wow! it works fine now. Included the extension in shader "#extension GL_EXT_draw_instanced : enable" and used "gl_InstanceIDEXT" variable done a trick. thanks.

Comment: One more edit needed in your answer, Instanced draw calls are possible in OpenGLES 2.0 using  glDrawElementsInstancedEXT and glDrawArraysInstancedEXT.